# Where should an application config overriding method be placed in a Rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, scope

I'm using a GEM of my own, which defines an application (appA) config variable (varA) in its initializers. However, I want the value of this variable (varA) to be used just as a default and I would like to create a method (metA) in the GEM (appA) which would give the possibility to override the value of the config variable (varA).

I want to call this method (metA) from the application which uses the GEM (appB).

Where should I place the method (metA)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the config variable as:

```
module YourGem
  mattr_accessor :option_a
  @@option_a = "default value"
end
```

And override it in `config/initializers/your_gem.rb`:

```
YourGem.option_a = "new value"
```

Comment: What file should be the first snippet go?

Comment: In your Gem, I assumed that it is a module.